# Unity Global Menu not working in Firefox 70 (latest beta)

Tags: unity, firefox

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTBLi.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY7Qy.png)

As you can probably see in these screenshots, the menu is not integrating into Unity.

I guess that's what I get for using a deprecated DE, but I'm holding out hope that there's a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Officially, non of Mozilla products support the global menu (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1419151). The support of the global menu is in first place something that need to be supported by the toolkit and like Firefox have his own toolkit it need to be support that internally. So, how the support for the global menu in Firefox is not included by default, this is included then thanks to some externals developers. To be more specific, this was supported on Ubunt-Unity only because the Ubuntu developers merged a patch with the original source of Firefox. Also the same patch was apply in several linux distributions after that. You can find the original patch here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mozillateam/firefox/firefox-trunk.head/view/head:/debian/patches/unity-menubar.patch

Now that the Ubuntu developers drop Unity in favour of gnome shell, we can assumed that they will drop also the support for all this type of patches. So, the new versions of Firefox in Ubuntu will probably have soon a not updated patch that really will NOT work with the new sources of Firefox and will be retired.

This is not just for Firefox, but it's for a lot of applications that already have not a global menu in an officially way. In this applications the global menu is supported only because some external developer to that applications created a patch for it and probably they was also some Ubuntu developers. See as an example: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/1131664 Also please note in particular the comment **#61** of the previuslly link that confirms the direction of the Ubuntu developers about that.

In your case is probably worse because you are trying to run Firefox directly from an upstream source, but Firefox like a lot of officially GNOME applications have not upstream support for the global menu at all.

Comment: As of the latest FF packages in Ubuntu the patch has been updated and applied. Maybe they'll stop at some point, but not yet..

Comment: Yes, that is why i said "we can assumed", "will probably have" and "the direction of". I can not ensure what they will do with the specific FF case in the future and i think also nobody know rigth now what will happen. My main point is about that he have the "latest beta", so i can assume that he install FF from an upsetream source and then it have not the patch of ubuntu (see last paragraph of my comment). But most of my comment is in a warning tone, because nobody can ensure that the patch will continus be working in the future if have not a mantainer.